# Reset functionality is not working for Null/Not Null filters in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid, and it's columns contain filter toolbar with ~, !~, # & !# (i.e. contains, doesn't contain, null & not null) options. The filter functionality works fine for ~, !~, # & !#, but when I try to reset my filter by clicking 'x' button next to the text box. It never resets the grid for # & !# (i.e. null & not null).

I am using jqGrid-4.5.2 version.

Can any one help please.

Thanks
Santosh.

Comment: Hi @Oleg,   Can you please suggest whether it is a limitation of Jqgrid or I am missing out something.

Comment: 1) If you want to send a message to me you should write comment with `@Oleg` to **my old answer or to the answer/question where I wrote already a comment**. If you write comment to your question stackoverflow unable to resolve "Oleg" (there are a lot of accounts with the same name, but different user ids). 2) jqGrid 4.5.2 is more as 3 yeas old. It's dead. I recommend you to try whether the same problem exist with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.3. I can fix the bug  in the newest version of my fork of jqGrid (free jqGrid) 3) You should include JavaScript code.

Comment: OK @Oleg, thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, I have tried the same with 4.13.3 free jqGrid. Still the problem exists. Can you please help.

Comment: I can help you only if I can reproduce the problem and debug it. Could you provide the demo, which I can use to reproduce the problem? Which web browser you used in your tests? Additionally I'm not sure that I correctly understand your problem. If you use **local** filtering, then not all operation can be used by default, but free jqGrid allows you to define your custom operation and to implement, how it should work. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Custom-filtering-searching-Operation)

Comment: See [some other old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A315935+customSortOperations) too.